# Python error using SSL certificate with proxy

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I am accessing an https page through a proxy:

```
    def read_page(self,url):
    '''
    Gets web page using proxy and returns beautifulsoup object
    '''
    soup = None
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, proxies=PROXIES, auth=PROXY_AUTH,
             cert = ('../static/crawlera-ca.crt'), verify=False,allow_redirects=False)
    except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema:
        return False

    if r.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
        if soup:
            return soup
    return False
```

I am passing "https://www.bestbuy.com" as the url. I get this error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.bestbuy.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(336265225, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2964)'),))
```

When I remove the `cert = ('../static/crawlera-ca.crt')` argument, the program accesses the site successfully giving me an 'InsecureRequestWarning', which is expected. But I don't understand why the other error happens. The certificate file is in the right place in my folder hierarchy, and was downloaded from the proxy service, so I know it's right.

The easy option would be to just not use the certificate and suppress the security warning, but I want to do it properly. Can anyone explain what is going on and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the meaning of the `cert` parameter. This is not the (list of) trusted CA you seem to think but this parameter is for the client certificate you use to authenticate yourself against the server. And, such a certificate for authentication also requires a matching private key.

Given that it works without this parameter the server obviously does not need a client certificate from you (which is uncommon anyway). You've probably meant instead to use `../static/crawlera-ca.crt` as the list of trusted CA for certificate validation instead. In this case you should not use the `cert` parameter but use the `verify` parameter like this:

```
  r = requests.get(url, proxies=PROXIES, auth=PROXY_AUTH,
         verify = '../static/crawlera-ca.crt', 
         allow_redirects=False)
```

For more information see the [documentation of cert parameter](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates) and how to use it in authentication with client certificates and [how to use verify](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) in server certificate validation.